# Sub packages and __init__.py

Tags: python

So, this is a set of questions about how to use __init__.py in packages/sub-packages. I have searched, and surprisingly not found a decent answer to this.

If I have the following structure (which is just a simplified example obviously):

```
my_package/
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  my_sub_package/
    __init__.py
    module2.py
```

the contents of module1.py is

```
my_string = 'Hello'
```

the contents of module2.py is

```
my_int = 42
```

### First question: importing multiple modules from a package by default

What should be in the __init__.py files?

I can leave them empty, in which case, `import my_package` does nothing really (obviously it imports the package, but the package effectively contains nothing). This is fine obviously, and what should happen in most cases.

What I'd like in this case though is for `import my_package` to allow me to use `my_package.module1.my_string` and `my_package.my_sub_package.module2.my_int`.

I can add `__all__ = [ 'module1' ]` to my_package/__init__.py and `__all__ = [ 'module2' ]` to my_package/my_sub_package/__init__.py, but this only affects imports using a wildcard as I understand it (so only `from my_package import *` and `from my_package.my_sub_package import *`).

I can achieve this by putting

```
import my_package.module1
import my_package.my_sub_package
```

in my_package/__init__.py and

```
import my_package.my_sub_package.module2
```

in my_package/my_sub_package/__init__.py, but is this a bad idea? It creates a (seemingly) infinite series of my_package.my_package.my_package.... when I do this in the Python interpreter (3.5.5).

### Separate, but highly related, question: using modules to keep files reasonably sized

If I wanted instead to be able to do the following

```
import my_package
print(my_package.my_string)
print(str(my_package.my_sub_package.my_int))
```

i.e. I wanted to use module1 and module2 purely for separating code into smaller more readable files if I actually had lots of modules in each package (which obviously doesn't apply in this trivial example, but can easily)

is doing `from my_package.module1 import *` in my_package/__init__.py and `from my_package.my_sub_package.module2 import *` in my_package/my_sub_package/__init__.py a reasonable way to do that? I don't like the use of the wildcard import, but it seems like it would be impractically verbose to import everything defined in a (real) module, listing them all.

### Third (also highly related) question: avoiding writing the package names in multiple places

Is there a way I can achieve the above without having to put the names of the packages into the source code in them? I ask because I'd like to avoid having to change it in multiple places if I renamed the package (again, simple in this trivial example, can be done by an IDE or script in reality, but would be nice to know how to avoid).

Comment: If you have several questions - even when related - please ask each question seperately.

Comment: Too many questions indeed, but OTHO they are really so closely related that asking them separately wouldn't really make sense...

Comment: Don't have time to write a proper answer here, so just one _very_ important point: using star imports in the `__init__.py` and hacking a way to avoid "having to put the names of the packages into the source code" are __VERY__ bad ideas in the long run - been here, done that, and this was a pure maintainance nightmare. Being explicit about what you import and from where has HUGE advantages wrt/ readability and maintainability, and actually makes renaming / refactoring easier (because you know where everything comes from).

Comment: For the second part of your question (which should actually read "using _packages_ to keep _modules_ reasonably sized"), this is a very common pattern - you have a "mymodule.py" file, it grows too huge, you turn it into a "mymodule" package ("mymodule" dirrectory + `__init__.py + submodules) and use the `__init__.py` as a facade for what you want to expose from the submodules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `my_package/__init__.py`, use

```
from . import my_sub_package
```

etc.
See for example NumPy's `__init__.py`, which has `from . import random`, and allows

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random
```

Wildcard imports inside a single package tend to be common, provided you have `__all__` defined in the modules and subpackages you import from.
Again an example from NumPy's `__init__.py`, which has several wildcard imports.

Here's part of that `__init__.py`:

```
from . import core
from .core import *
from . import compat
from . import lib
from .lib import *
from . import linalg
from . import fft
from . import polynomial
from . import random
from . import ctypeslib
from . import ma
from . import matrixlib as _mat
from .matrixlib import *
from .compat import long
```

Notice also the two `core` import lines. Both `numpy.core` and the core definitions (functions, classes etc) are then available.

When in doubt how to do something, or whether something is good practice, have a look at a few well-known libraries or packages. That can help gaining some valuable insights.

Comment: thanks for this. i have a question. I have looked at the `__init__.py` of `random` folder(sub-package) of `numpy` and 'random' folder is also being imported in the `__init__.py` inside numpy folder(main package) the way you mentioned. so, when i do `import numpy as np`, will this not generate two copies of all the sub-packages, like `np.random`, since, in python3, importing a package runs the `__init__.py` files of package and all it's sub-packages?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala I'm not sure what you ask exactly, but two things to note: 1/ `numpy.__init__.py` doesn't specifically import `random.__init__.py`, but it uses `from . import random`. Thus, it imports the full subpackage, under that subpackage's name(space). As a result, you can directly use `numpy.random` once you've done `import numpy` in your own code;

Comment: (cont) 2/ Using `import numpy.random` after doing `import numpy` doesn't add overhead, and then using `numpy.random.<function>` works the same. Even if you do `from numpy import random`, you'll get the same effect, but now you have imported the subpackage namespace into your code, so you can use it more directly. But in all cases, no copies will be created: just a few namespace "pointers", for user/coder convenience.