# why can't i import my own folder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

My folder structure is:

- `rottParser/`

  - `__init__.py`
- `rottSyntax/`

  - `__init__.py`
- `rottTests/`

I'm trying to import `rottSyntax` into `rottParser`,
in my IDE (pycharm) it works, but in my python console it doesn't.

The error was:

```
[ari@ari-manjaro rottParser]$ python3.9 __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ari/Desktop/coding/python_/rott/rottParser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rottSyntax import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rottSyntax'
```

as said before, in py IDE it all worked,

here's the `rottParser/__init__.py`:

```py
import sys
from rottSyntax import *

parse_file = sys.argv
print(parse_file)

c = '.hello'
a = syntax['comment'].search(c)
print(a)
```

and `rottSyntax/__init__.py`:

```py
import re
syntax = {
    "comment": re.compile(r'^\..+')
}
```

I tried just importing it and with a `.`, and nothing worked,
anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Where/which is your entry script? And, you tried `from . import *` instead of `from rottSyntax import *`?

Comment: yes i tried from . import *, and i'm trying to import rottSyntax/__init__.py to rottParser/__init__.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sub packages and \_\_init\_\_.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498113/sub-packages-and-init-py)

Comment: Please add the script that does the import as well and where it is located! Thanks

Comment: @Wolf [ghchoi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086713/14842316) answer worked:DD

Comment: @Ari157 that's nice for you but think of all the other people seeing your question, please be so kind and add this detail, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Very quick fix 1

Execute the script like the followings:

```sh
PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH python rottParser/__init__.py
```

or

```sh
cd rottParser
PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH python __init__.py
```

#### Very quick fix 2

Append a path to `sys.path` from `rottParser/__init__.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/PATH/TO/rottParser/..')  # parent directory
from rottSyntax import *
```

#### Relative Imports

To used
[Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), `rottParser` and `rottSyntax` should be subpackages.

With the following structure,

```
├ rott
│ ├ rottParser/
│ │  └ __init__.py
│ └ rottSyntax/
│    └ __init__.py
└ main.py
```

and `main.py`

```
import rott.rottParser
```

you can use relative imports, e.g., from `rottParser/__init__.py`

```
from ..rottSyntax import *
```

If you want

```
from .rottSyntax import *
```

directory structure should belike

```
│ └ rottParser/
│    ├ __init__.py
│    └ rottSyntax/
│      └ __init__.py
```

Comment: doesn't work;//
```
[ari@ari-manjaro rottParser]$ python3.9 __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ari/Desktop/coding/python_/rott/rottParser/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rottSyntax import SYNTAX
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rottSyntax'
```

Comment: @Ari157 What is your `init.py` and where is it? Is it `__init__.py`?

Comment: it's `__init__.py`, i want to import `rottSyntax/__init__.py` to `rottParser/__init__.py`

Comment: @Ari157 Made an edit. I do not know the name of the root directory so I used `..` notation, however, you would better use the absolute path to the root directory.

Comment: @Ari157 I will add an intra-package reference example as well.

Comment: Nice to have the reference here, maybe the "quick"s could be go now, I'd try a bit of polishing...