# Cannot import partially initialized subpackage

Tags: python, python-packaging

So, this is a question about how to use __init__.py with sub-packages. I have searched, and surprisingly not found a decent answer to this.

I have the following structure:

```
my_package/
setup.py
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
            my_sub_package/
            __init__.py
            module2.py
```

The contents of my_package/__init__.py is

```
from . import my_sub_package
from .module1 import *
```

The contents of my_package/my_sub_package/__init__.py is

```
from .module2 import *
```

The contents of setup.py is

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='My Package',
    packages=['my_package'],
    version='1.0.0'
)
```

I'm able to import the package in python from parent folder using:

```
import my_package
```

The problem arises when I install the package and run this in another folder (not containing my_package).
I install the package using:

```
pip3 install my_package/ --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Then, when I try to import it in Python

```
import my_package
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'my_sub_package' from partially
> initialized module 'my_package' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (<PYTHON_PATH>/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my_package/__init__.py)

What am I doing wrong?

I am doing exactly as they say in this answer: [Sub packages and __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498113/sub-packages-and-init-py)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem lies in setup.py, where I need to specify that also my_sub_package is a package:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='My Package',
    packages=['my_package','my_package.my_sub_package],
    version='1.0.0'
)
```

An even better solution is to use `find_packages`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='My Package',
    packages= find_packages(),
    version='1.0.0'
)
```